# Ruby gets.chomp and class inheritance

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

I've been trying to write a code for checking whether the number is a leap year with class inheritance. But I got an error message on the second line which starts with `year`:

```
Line 7: private method `chomp' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I want to make users type the years and then return the responses respectively ---"It's a leap year!" or "Oops! It's not a leap year". But it seems to me that `gets.chomp` and `class` collide with each other. How can I solve this problem?

Below is my code(I amended the former one yet it still doesn't work):

```
class Year
  def initialize(year)
    @@year = year
  end

  puts "Type the year to see whether it is a leap year!"
  year = gets.chomp
end


class DivideIt
  def initialize(year)
    @year = year
  end

  if @year % 4 == 0 || @year % 100 != 0 || @year % 400 == 0
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end

year < DivideIt
```

Thank you. :)

Comment: Do you mean `DivideIntoFHund`'s divide method will check all the three condition defined in parent classes?

Comment: three condition?? I meant DivideIntoFHund which inherit condition from DivideIntoFour and DivideIntoHund in order would  check the given number(year = gets.chomp).

Comment: Start with formatting your code and closing opened class definitions. `gets.chomp` is just a victim of poor code below.

Comment: hmmm some of your classes doesn't have matching `end` clauses, anyway you should have gotten syntax error , gets.chomp shouldn't be the line of error !

Comment: your code shows `syntax error` as expected with me, what ruby version are you using ?!!!

Comment: I commend the intent to master the concepts and practice of inheritance, but think this is a very inappropriate use of it.  The three operations can easily be represented as methods, and when a simple and complex solution exist, one should choose the simpler one.  Also, you can massively trim the size of your methods by simply using the expression, e.g. year % 100 != 0, and leave out all the if/else/end's.

Comment: I agree with keith, anyway your code doesn't show any errors like you said, is this the only code you're running ? what ruby version do you have ?

Comment: I think your error relates to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/2nqr6j/error_undefined_method_chomp_for_nilnilclass/)

Comment: I use Ruby 2.3.0. BTW I made an amendment to my code, but it still prints out the same error. What should I do... :( Anyway I shall check niceman's suggestion. Thank you all !

Comment: You should wrap any code which is inside class definition and outside method to a meaningful method like in class `Year` (`year = gets.chomp`) otherwise it will execute only once when class definition is executed.

Comment: I would suggest you to try only 'year = gets.chomp' in console, which will give you the hint if anything is wrong with `gets`

Comment: Using `@@year`, which is a class instance variable, is probably not what you want here, instead use `@year` which is instance specific. Likewise, including arbitrary code in the body of a class that takes user input will work, but is really bad from an organization point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
year = gets.chomp
```

to

```
year = gets.to_s.chomp
```

Calling `to_s` will convert your `nil` to an empty string.